# sonarqube test coverage with istanbul : No coverage property. Skip Sensor

Tags: javascript, testing, sonarqube, test-coverage

I'm trying to output some test coverage (lcov) reports from istanbul into sonarqube to analyse our test coverage using thoughtworks GO. There is a coverage/html folder being output but sonarqube reports the following error No coverage property. Skip Sensor. Here's my properties file, what am I missing ?

```
sonar.projectKey=transformers.allspark.ui
sonar.projectName=Transformers Allspark UI
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube-security.test.ctmers.io
sonar.sources=.
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.language=js
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/html
```

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Is your coverage report named exactly "html"?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responding. I've managed to fix this by replacing the last line with this : sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/html/lcov.info. It appears that sonarqube needs a path to a file (lcov.info) and not just the folder. Also my istanbul configuration was wrong because it needed to output lcov and not just a standard report.